# Too late to hill?

Tags: growth, potatoes, stems

So time got away from me and the stems got to be over a foot high before I could hill them over.  Is it too late now or will they still grow in after they're good and hilled.  They have not even started to look like they're budding if that helps.  I'm sure this will negatively impact the yield.  Thanks!

Comment: What plant are we talking about, here?

Comment: Potatoes.  Thank you in advance.